# Why might a person get widely varying scores on different online IQ tests?

Tags: intelligence, test, internet

Online IQ tests often yield wildly varying results (say 60 - 150). These are actual values obtained by repeated measures. It is puzzling, because it's such a wide range. How can the same person be mentally retarded and a genius at the same time?

Comment: Because most online tests are worthless and generally more interested in getting traffic than to provide an accurate result.

Answer (score 9):

[Firmin et al. (2008)](http://digitalcommons.cedarville.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1006&context=psychology_publications&sei-redir=1&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fscholar.google.com%2Fscholar%3Fion%3D1%26espv%3D2%26bav%3Don.2%2Cor.r_cp.%26bvm%3Dbv.87920726%2Cd.aWw%26biw%3D1423%26bih%3D701%26dpr%3D1%26um%3D1%26ie%3DUTF-8%26lr%26q%3Drelated%3A1mCrasWnQQb4qM%3Ascholar.google.com%2F#search=%22related%3A1mCrasWnQQb4qM%3Ascholar.google.com%2F%22) tested the validity of a handful of online IQ tests by having college students complete IQ tests at three different websites and also complete a validated lab measure, the Reynolds Intellectual Assessment Scales (RIAS). They found that there were moderate correlations ($r$ values were around 0.4 to 0.5) between some of the online tests and the RIAS, though other tests did not have a significant correlation with the RIAS. Thus, there was some evidence that online IQ tests are measuring the same kinds of things as lab-based IQ tests, but the correlations were weak and some tests were better than others.

In short: online IQ tests are widely variable in their validity, and even the good ones are probably not all that accurate.

**Reference**

Firmin, M., Hwang, C., Burger, A., Sammons, J., & Lowrie, R. (2008). Evaluating the concurrent validity of three web-based IQ tests
and the Reynolds Intellectual Assessment Scales (RIAS). *Eastern Education Journal, 37*, 20-28.